# Identifying the WLM job picked my stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, mainframe

How could we know which WLM job has picked my DB2 stored procedure call invoked. I see some set of jobs are running with `DB2XWLM*` where `DB2X` is database region. But how to check which particular job had taken my stored procedure call.

Hope I made clear, please let me know if something is not clear. Appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 1):

By giving few 'unique display statements' in the Stored procedure and by making the display statements on , we can check which WLMjob has picked the Stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a stored procedure is assigned to a region when it's created.

If you are able to see the DDL for the CREATE PROCEDURE statement (perhaps through DB2 admin tool), there should be a line like:

```
WLM ENVIRONMENT DB2SP3
```

DB2SP3 would be the environment your stored procedure lives in.  I'm not sure that it always works this way, but it's worth checking.

Comment: I'm sure which `environment` the `stored procedure` resides in, but once you run the `stored procedure`, that will execute via some set of `WLMjobs`. I wanna know which `WLMjob` has taken my stored procedure

Comment: Hmm, I think they have it so that the proc runs in whatever address space it was defined to.  Sorry - didn't know it could be allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the job output where you can see display statements of your SP. That JCL has WLM specified. Just search for WLM word and you can find it.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an old post but here is the answer for future reference:

```
select schema ,owner ,name ,WLM_ENVIRONMENT
  from SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES
 where schema = 'yourschemaname'
   and name = 'yourSPname'
```

`WLM_environment` is the column you are looking for. 
(db2v11)